# Django and Dynamic model relationships

Tags: django, django-models

I have one main model :

```
ToolBox
```

and three other models :

```
Hammer
Nail
Plier
```

Obviously a ToolBox can contain any combination of Hammers, Nails or Pliers.

Using Django, what is a good ORM representation of this dynamic type of relationship? Bare in mind that each of these models can have its own rich set of attributes so a simple type field won't do the job. I am also wondering how the admin interface in Django can be fine tuned to this dynamic type of thing if it works.

Comment: So a many-to-many relation between each tool and the toolbox could be what you are looking for.

Comment: It sounds like you will want a many to many field to a model with a generic key.

This could be represented in the admin with the through table as an inline, but it will get expensive to query this model as each inline will have to lookup a different table.

You could pare it down to 1 query per content_type + content type query if you want a little more performance.

Comment: Why not using inheritance ? Hammer, Nail and Plier could inherit from a « Tool » model and this one could be linked to any ToolBox with a many to many relationship.

Comment: Performance isn't a big issue. Actually I'm trying to model a CMS database where UI parts gets to be associated with one of several elements, ex: Text, image, video so that the user is able using the admin interface to specify each part separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by dynamic, your example is quite typical I think.

But anyway, in order to avoid the situation:

```
Toolbox
    many2many(Hammer)
    many2many(Nail)
    etc... (add new m2m field every time you add another tool class)
```

I would do it like this:

```
Toolbox

Hammer
    foreignkey(Toolbox)

Nail
    foreignkey(Toolbox)
```

This will make things much easier to implement (use toolbox.hammer_set, etc). 
If the Hammer, Nail, etc have some fields in common you can also define an abstract base class (e.g. Tool) that holds all common fields.